# Proof with triangle with similar triangles formed by medians

Tags: geometry

[image]

Use similar triangles to prove that $|AS|:|SD|=|BS|:|SE|=2:1$.

---

My try:

$|AE|=|EC|$, $|BD|=|DC|$ $\Rightarrow \triangle ABC \sim \triangle EDC$

$\Rightarrow \angle A=\angle E \Rightarrow AB \parallel ED$

$\Rightarrow \angle BAD=\angle ADE$, $\angle ABE=\angle DEB$

$\Rightarrow \triangle ABS\sim \triangle DES$

From here, I can't prove the ratios..

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $|AB|=2|ED|$, because $\frac {|AB|}{|ED|}=\frac{|AC|}{|EC|}=2$. Now, the ratio between $\triangle ABS$ and $\triangle DES$ is $2$ too, and thus it follows that $$\frac{|BS|}{|ES|}=\frac{|AB|}{|DE|}=\frac{|AC|}{|EC|}=2$$

Comment: I can't see how to deduct that the ratio between $\triangle ABS$ and $\triangle DES$ is 2 too..

Comment: Please check all $=$-signs on the last line carefully and tell me which one you don't understand.

Comment: I already understand, thank you so much! ;-) Bedankt!

Comment: Could I ask something? Do you know a good book for practicing these problems? I now use Moderne Wiskunde, but I'd love to practice more.

Comment: Have a look here: http://finaletrainingutrecht.tk/ (My training site of the Dutch Mathematical Olympiad.) At the bottom is a link to a book with similar exersizes. ('opgavenboekje')

Comment: Bedankt! Ga ik zeker gebruiken ;-)